Lazy loading angular child routes with no common url ancestor
I'm using angular 15. In my main module's routing, I've got the following routes to lazy load the MediaModule
  {
    path: 'video-page',
    loadChildren: () => import('app/myapp/submodules/media.module').then(m => m.MediaModule),
  },
  
  
  {
    path: 'image-page',
    loadChildren: () => import('app/myapp/submodules/media.module').then(m => m.MediaModule),
  },
  {
     path: '',
     import('app/myapp/submodules/hp.module').then(m => m.HPModule),
  },
  
  

Here is my routing from the MediaModule:
{
    path: 'video-page/:documentId',
    component: VideoPageComponent,
    //pathMatch:'full',
    data: {
      breadcrumb: 'Media page'
    }
  },

  {
    path: 'video-page/:documentId/:documentTitle',
    component: VideoPageComponent,
    data: {
      breadcrumb: 'Media page'
    }
  },

  {
    path: 'image-page/:imageId',
    component: ImagePageComponent,
    data: {
      breadcrumb: 'Image page'
    }
  },

  {
    path: 'image-page/:imageId/:imageTitle',
    component: ImagePageComponent,
    data: {
      breadcrumb: 'Image page'
    }
  }

Now I want both the urls video-page/:documentId and video-page/:documentId/:title to lazy load the MediaModule and display the VideoPageComponent component and the  urls image-page/:imageId and image-page/:imageId/:title to lazy load the MediaModule and display the ImageComponent
How can I modify the routing to achieve this? All my tries result to either a 404, or only of the the routes working. I tried modifiying pathMatch, but it does not seems to work. If I remove 'image-page' or 'video-page' from the MediaModule routing, then the router cannot differentiate between image and video pages. And I do want to have them in the same module, since they share many common components

First move the roots to the child module, so that you can have a single definnition in app module. Then implement children to render the routes dynamically.
[
  {
    path: 'video-page',
    children: [
      {
        path: ':documentId',
        component: VideoPageComponent,
        //pathMatch:'full',
        data: {
          breadcrumb: 'Media page',
        },
      },
      {
        path: ':documentId/:documentTitle',
        component: VideoPageComponent,
        data: {
          breadcrumb: 'Media page',
        },
      },
  },
  {
    path: 'image-page',
    children: [
      {
        path: ':imageId',
        component: ImagePageComponent,
        data: {
          breadcrumb: 'Image page',
        },
      },
      {
        path: ':imageId/:imageTitle',
        component: ImagePageComponent,
        data: {
          breadcrumb: 'Image page',
        },
      },
  },
]

app.routing.ts
 {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('app/myapp/submodules/media.module').then(m => m.MediaModule),
  },


The path: '' already redirects to my home page. I cannot change the urls

@David There can be multiple what is essential is that, if one blank module does not get a match, it will move on to the next one, it will take the first matching route

yes but in this case, it means that both the media module and the hp module will be loaded for the '' path.

@David just try it, the end application will show the proper output in the URL, this is a design problem, to solve this, you need to split the MediaModule into VideoModule and ImageModule, if you want it like that
